# How to use CkEditor binded with Razor-Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor, model-binding

In my Razor, I am using a model-binded textarea as :

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.myHtml, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I am also replacing the Textarea with CKEditor as:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('myHtml');
```

Now, during the postback to controller action, "myHtml" always shows as null.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public void PostModal(myModel modle)
        {// here modle.myHtml is always null.
}
```

My Model is defined as:

```
 public class myModel
    {
        public string myHtml { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried below workarounds:

1) Removed CKEditor, tried to bind the textarea with model and it WORKED FINE. I was able to get value in the controller post method.
2) Tried to use  [ValidateInput(false)] - NO GO
3) Tried to decorate the model property with  [DataType(DataType.Html)] - NOGO
4) CKEDITOR.instances.myHtml.getData() shows correct value on button click, which means its an issue with the model binding.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

-Shalabh

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Inspect the textarea CKEditor is replacing and ensure that it's being backfilled by CKEditor with what you're adding in the HTML editor. You'll need `[AllowHtml]` on your `myHtml` property, or you'll get an exception, but that doesn't explain why nothing is being posted. My only other thought is to post the actual code, as it looks like this is just representative code you created for the purpose of the question. It's possible there's something in your actual code that is not be reproduced here.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your suggestions and apologies for my delayed reply.

I have tried with [AllowHtml] attribute before, but it seems to be no longer available for MVC5. The code I have shared is the actual code with slight name modifications. 

Also, I was able to resolve the issue by manually assigning the value from CKeditor to the textarea , on the Modal button click --> Client side.

$('#myHtml').val(CKEDITOR.instances.myHtml.getData());